# Angle chasing in the triangle with incenter

Tags: geometry

> In a triangle $ABC$ if $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are the angle bisectors of $\angle A$, $\angle B$ $\angle C$ respectively with incenter $I$ and let $\angle BAC=2x$, $\angle ABC=2y$, $\angle ACB=2z$. Find all the possible angle in the triangle $DEF$ in term of $x,y,z$

I was able to find $\angle CID=\angle AIF=x+z$, $\angle BIF=\angle CIE=y+z$ and $\angle BID=\angle AIE=x+y$
[image]
I wasn't able to find $\angle IFD$,$\angle IDF$, $\angle IDE$, $\angle IED$, $\angle IEF$, $\angle IFE$. Please help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a 100% way to calculate angles of $EFD$ with a bit of trig.

Let $AB=c$, $BC=a$, $CA=b$. $\frac{BD}{DC}= \frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{c}{b}$, and $BD+DC = a \implies$ $$CD = \frac{ab}{b+c}, BD =\frac{ca}{b+c}.$$
Similarly, we can see that $$BF = \frac{bc}{a+b}, FA =\frac{ac}{a+b}.$$ $$AE = \frac{ab}{a+c}, EC =\frac{bc}{a+c}.$$ Now, we can apply cos theorem in $\triangle AFE: FE^2 = AF^2+AE^2-2\cdot AF \cdot AE \cdot cos(\angle A) = (\frac{ac}{a+b})^2+(\frac{ab}{a+c})^2-2\cdot \frac{ab}{a+c} \cdot \frac{ac}{a+b} \cdot \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} = a^2(\frac{c^2}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a+c)(a+b)})= \frac{a^2(a + b + c) (-a^3 + 2 a b^2 + b^3 - a b c + 2 a c^2 + c^3)}{(a+b)^2(a+c)^2}\implies $ $$FE^2 = \frac{a^2(a + b + c)(b^3+c^3-a^3-abc+2ab^2+2ac^2)}{(a+b)^2(a+c)^2}$$ $$FD^2 = \frac{b^2(a + b + c)(a^3+c^3-b^3-abc+2ba^2+2bc^2)}{(b+a)^2(b+c)^2}$$ $$ED^2 = \frac{c^2(a + b + c)(a^3+b^3-c^3-abc+2ca^2+2cb^2)}{(c+a)^2(c+b)^2}.$$ Now you can see that $$EF^2=FD^2+DE^2-2\cdot FD \cdot FE \cdot cos(\angle FDE)\implies cos(\angle FDE)=\frac{FD^2+DE^2-EF^2}{2 \cdot FD \cdot FE}=\frac{b^2(a^3+c^3-b^3-abc+2ba^2+2bc^2)(a+c)^2+c^2(a^3+b^3-c^3-abc+2ca^2+2cb^2)(a+c)^2-a^2(b^3+c^3-a^3-abc+2ab^2+2ac^2)(b+c)^2}{2ab\sqrt{(b^3+c^3-a^3-abc+2ab^2+2ac^2)(a^3+c^3-b^3-abc+2ba^2+2bc^2)}(a+b)(b+c)} = \frac{2 a^5 b^2 + 2 a^5 b c + 2 a^5 c^2 + 2 a^4 b^3 + 2 a^4 b^2 c + 4 a^4 c^3 - 2 a^3 b^4 - a^3 b^2 c^2 - 4 a^3 b c^3 + 3 a^3 c^4 - 2 a^2 b^5 - 2 a^2 b^4 c + 2 a^2 b^3 c^2 + 2 a^2 b^2 c^3 - 4 a^2 b c^4 - 2 a b^5 c + 5 a b^3 c^3 + 6 a b^2 c^4 - a b c^5 - 2 a c^6 - b^5 c^2 + 3 b^3 c^4 + 3 b^2 c^5 - c^7}{2ab\sqrt{(b^3+c^3-a^3-abc+2ab^2+2ac^2)(a^3+c^3-b^3-abc+2ba^2+2bc^2)}(a+b)(b+c)}$$.

Note, that $a:b:c = sin(\angle A): sin(\angle B): sin(\angle C) = sin(2x):sin(2y):sin(2z)$. Plug this back you will find $\angle EDF$ in terms of $x,y,z$